# If diborane has 3c-2e bonds, then why are both boron atoms still electron deficit?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, hydrides

This is an image of the structure of diborane.

[image]

It has a 3-center-2-electron bridge bond.

As we can see in the bridge bond, the electron in the hydrogen atom and one electron in either boron atom is shared between the hydrogen and boron atoms two times, making two $\ce{B-H-B}$ bridges. Does this mean that both boron atoms as well as the hydrogen atom share those 2 electrons? If this is true, then both borons' octet should be satisfied since the 2 electrons are shared equally between all 3 atoms. So why are both boron atoms still electron deficit?

These are the sources confirming that boron has an electron deficit.

- Chemistry LibreTexts: https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Inorganic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_and_Websites_(Inorganic_Chemistry)/Descriptive_Chemistry/Elements_Organized_by_Block/2_p-Block_Elements/Group_13%3A_The_Boron_Family/Z005_Chemistry_of_Boron_(Z5)/Boranes_and_Borohydrides
- [*Coord. Chem. Rev.* **2002,** *226* (1-2), 61–69](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0010-8545(01)00433-7)
- Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diborane

Comment: In this arrangement, Boron atom is not electron deficient. But the bonds are not typical covalent bonds as they are in $\ce{H2}$ molecules, for example.

Comment: @Maurice According to many online sources, diborane is indeed electron deficient. There are not enough valence electrons to form the expected number of covalent bonds. My question was asking why it as such.

Comment: Provide references and reasoning of such sources. If there are so many of them, they surely also say why or why not are boron atoms still electron deficient even in B2H6.  As depending on a point of view, they are and at the same time they are not electron deficient. ( They are not as they do deal with the full electron octet. They are, otherwise they would not need to achieve that by 3c-2e bond.)

Comment: If a 3c-2e bond was as good as two normal, you'd see them all the time.

Comment: In all of these sites, it mentions that the boron atoms in diborane are supposedly electron deficient. I am asking why it is so, since the 2 electrons in the bridge bond are shared equally between all atoms, boron's octet should be satisfied.

Comment: 3c-2e bond is electron deficient by its nature.

Comment: Thank you, could you please elaborate a little more on this, and post it as an answer to the question?

Comment: Quoting the wikipedia article to which you link: "Traditionally, diborane has often been described as electron-deficient, because the 12 valence electrons can only form 6 conventional 2-centre 2-electron bonds, which are insufficient to join all 8 atoms.[28][29] However, the more correct description using 3-centre bonds shows that diborane is really electron-precise, since there are just enough valence electrons to fill the 6 bonding molecular orbitals.[30] Nevertheless, some leading textbooks still use the term "electron-deficient". One of the references is to Bill Lipscomb's Nobel lecture.

Comment: If you don't know who Professor Lipscomb was see https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/chemistry/1976/lipscomb/facts/ - if anybody knew about boranes it was him. From his Nobel Prize Lecture: "One of the simple consequences of these studies was that electron deficient molecules, defined as having more valence orbitals than electrons, are not really electron deficient. I mean by this non-sequitur that the three-center two-electron bonds make possible a simple description of these molecules and ions as filled orbital species." https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2018/06/lipscomb-lecture.pdf

Comment: @IanBush that might as well be an answer. I don't think you would get to that conclusion in a better way.

Comment: Maybe later. I'm not sure I really know what "electron deficient" means. I'm not sure anybody does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well at least according to Professor William Lipscomb, who won a Nobel Prize "[for his studies on the structure of boranes illuminating problems of chemical bonding](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/chemistry/1976/lipscomb/facts/)", they are not electron deficient. Quoting from his [Nobel Prize lecture](https://www.nobelprize.org/uploads/2018/06/lipscomb-lecture.pdf)

> "One of the simple consequences of these studies was that electron
> deficient molecules, defined as having more valence orbitals than
> electrons, are not really electron deficient. I mean by this
> non-sequitur that the three-center two-electron bonds make possible a
> simple description of these molecules and ions as filled orbital
> species."

However as Wikipedia notes some leading text books still use this description. Personally I'm not sure I really *know* what is meant by "electron deficient", it being a term that seems to mean less and less with the more chemistry you know (c.f. hybridization). So I will bow to Professor Lipscomb's authority.

Comment: I think if it is or is not electron deficient depends on what is meant by that by the context. It may be both at the same time. In sense of using less valence electrons than the double of the bond count, it is electron deficient  In the sense you have described, it is not.

Comment: To be honest nowadays I would just solve for the orbitals and aufbau them with electrons. Let the maths do the talking, there is (usually) no ambiguity then

Comment: What I have meant that sometimes a term is not ambiguous, it just have more meanings and is good to explicitly say which one is assumed.

Comment: I just don't think it an especially useful term. Just marvel in the extraordinary variety of ways that atoms can combine. That, for me, is the wonder of Chemistry, Then get down to the maths.

Comment: I agree. Scientists often think nature does things this or that way, what is often true for a long time until they are shown the cases it does not.